# Getting unknown column in on clause, error 1054, for this SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

Im trying to get this SQL query to work. It wants me to list all product sales for which units sold is greater than the average units sold for that product. In addition to this I need to add a correlated in-line sub-query to the list of average units sold per product.

I created a decent chunk of code here that matches up the logic I was taught in class. The code is commented to describe what I am trying to accomplish with each unique block. I also add a TODO I need to make for the correlated sub query

```
SELECT * FROM invoice

-- Display sales data from invoice table

join product
on product.P_CODE = line.P_CODE

join line
on line.INV_NUMBER = invoice.INV_NUMBER

-- link tables together to bridge relevant data

having invoice.INV_TOTAL > avg(invoice.INV_TOTAL);

-- display the sales whose total is greater than the average total

/* TODO: Add a correlated in-line sub query to the list of 
average units sold per product here */
```

Trying to run the query above returns

Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'line.P_CODE' in 'on clause'

Comment: Thanks for highlighting the clauses @John Conde. I have no clue how to do that one myself

Comment: Debugging is part of programmer's job.  `FROM invoice join product on product.P_CODE = line.P_CODE` So where the `line.P_CODE` is coming from?  You only have table `invoice` and `product`.

Comment: Also `HAVING` without `GROUP BY`?

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and a description of the problem would help.  Your query doesn't make sense.  You are using `having` with no `group by`.  You are comparing an unaggregated column to the result of an aggregation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what problem you are trying to solve.  But if you want invoices whose total is greater than the average, then you don't need all the `join`s.  But you do need a calculation for the average in a subquery.

Something like this:

```
SELECT i.*
FROM invoice i
WHERE i.inv_total > (SELECT AVG(i2.inv_total)
                     FROM invoice i2);
```

You would join in the rest of the tables if you needed the columns from them.  And you can do that -- no `having` clause is needed, just the `where`.

If you want to do this for products, then it would be something like this

```
SELECT l.*
FROM lines l
WHERE l.units_sold > (SELECT AVG(l2.units_sold)
                      FROM lines l2);
```

This follows exactly the same pattern.

Comment: Thanks it looks like it did it. Im going to append a correlated line sub query at the end if I can and add a Sort by to sort the data from greatest to least descending

Answer (score 0):

Switch the positions of your `JOIN`s, i.e. `line` before `product`. And your `HAVING` makes no sense. Maybe you want to use a `WHERE` and a subquery getting the average.

```
SELECT *
       FROM invoice i1
            INNER JOIN line l1
                       ON l1.INV_NUMBER = i1.INV_NUMBER
            INNER JOIN product p1
                       ON p1.P_CODE = l1.P_CODE
       WHERE invoice.INV_TOTAL > (SELECT avg(i2.INV_TOTAL)
                                         FROM invoice i2);
```

And the presence of a column `INV_TOTAL` in `invoice`, presumably the sum of the quantity and price from the `line`s indicates you should normalize your schema here.